# how to force delete in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I made a user management system with soft deletion and force deletion options. However, I'm having trouble getting the force deletion option to work.

The route:

```
Route::post('users/{user}/delete', 'UserController@forcedelete');
```

The relevant controller code:

```
public function forcedelete(User $user)
{
     $user->forceDelete();
     return redirect('users/trash');
}
```

The view code:

```
<a href="{{ url('users/'.$user->id.'/delete') }}" 
   onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('delete').submit();">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o btn btn-danger btn-xs"></i>
</a>

<form id="delete" action="{{ url('users/'.$user->id.'/delete') }}" 
      method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
</form>
```

The error that I'm getting is

```
 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:
```

Why is it not working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: you can not use same method name for your controller, please update method name and try.

Comment: my soft delete method name only destroy                                                                             'public function destroy(User $user)
    {
       $user->delete();
       return redirect('users');
    }'

Comment: yes, then use that or you can use something like this `forceDestory`.

Comment: not works this code. problem same MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233:

Comment: ohh, which method you're using when calling delete call?

Comment: $user->forceDestroy();

Comment: please show your html form..

Comment: i update my post & here is view code

Comment: you are passing user id from your html. So change your controller function to be `public function forcedelete($user)` and get the user object in your forceDelete method. Or update your html to pass the user object instead of id. `('users/'.$user.'/delete')`

Comment: i have already forcedelete(User $user)

Comment: @AnitaYip don't give wrong answers if you don't know how route model binding works. How can one even pass an object in the url? masum check my answer

Comment: @Masum you have `forcedelete(User $user)`. My suggestion was to use `forcedelete($user)`. Drop the type declaration so that the {user} you declared in your route matches with the string argument of forcedelete function

Comment: @Sandeesh please feel free to correct if someone provides an incorrect statement. But make sure to keep a respectable tone in your comment. Keep in mind, no one intentionally provides an incorrect answer. My intention was to suggest him to try out the 2nd part of my comment though I know the first part of it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try placing this route above your other user routes or user resource route. Also you're trying to use route model binding with a soft deleted model, which won't work. You need to use the id and delete it manually.

```
public function forcedelete($id)
{
    User::where('id', $id)->forceDelete();
    return redirect('users/trash');
}
```

Edit: Also delete `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` from your form, since the route method defined is post.

Comment: WARNING: is `forceDelete()` not `forcedelete()`

Answer (score 5):

Methods to remove/restore records from the table. Laravel 5.x, 6.x, 7.x

To enable [soft deletes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models) for a model, use the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` **trait** on the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

**Soft delete:**
This will move record to trash

```
$user= User::find($id);
$user->delete();
```

**Force Delete:** Permanently Deleting Models

```
$user= User::withTrashed()->find($id);
$user->forceDelete();
```

**Restore:** Restoring Soft Deleted Models

```
$user= User::withTrashed()->find($id);
$user->restore();
```